# Windows 11 randomly restarting or showing black screen

Tags: drivers, freeze, windows-11

I have a new laptop with Windows 11. All of a sudden it started restarting by itself. It would never happen when I was working on it but would come back and everything had been closed. I followed some of the suggestions from [this article](https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/windows-11-random-restart.html#:%7E:text=It%20can%20be%20caused%20by,unsaved%20work%20due%20to%20this.)

1. Disabled automatic restart on failure. Now the screen just turns black and I have to manually restart.
2. Used SFC /scannow. Corruptions were found and fixed.
3. Run a CHKDSK Scan
4. Run a virus Scan - nothing found.
5. Run Windows updates and update device drivers.
6. Disable fast startup
7. Create registry key NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUser in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows.
8. Update group policy

Anything else I can try? Event viewer shows several critical errors from NetBT relating to drivers not being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laptop is new (you said) and so should be under warranty.

Do not to anything major that would invalidate the warranty.

I suggest running DISM prior to SFC.

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

Once the DISM / SFC steps have been run, run Windows Updates again including Optional Updates to get driver updates.

Then, another thing you can do (which will not affect warranty) is to get the Manufacturer's Hardware Test App and test all hardware for issues.

Then if you still have issues, contact Manufacturer Support for Repair or Replacement.

The manufacturer may ask you / require you to return the Operating System to the original condition (factory installation) and then test.  It is possible software you installed might have caused the issue.

Comment: For interment problems like this do you have any suggestions on how to test if it's been fixed?

Comment: You can get the Manufacturer's Hardware Test App and test all hardware for issues.  I did add this item to my answer.